# How to get the old value in an OnChange function in LotusScript?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a field called StartDate, and the field's OnChange function has a loop similar to this:

```
Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument
While Not (doc Is Nothing)
    If (doc.Username = somevalue) Then
        If (doc.StartDate(0) = specialdate) Then
            ' Do something here
        End if
    End if
    Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
Wend
```

My problem is that doc.StartDate holds the new value of the field but I want the old one. How do I get the field's previous value? Basically I need to compare the field's old value with its new value.

Comment: If you are setting `doc` variable by looping through `view` then `doc.StartDate` is not holds the new value of the field because `NotesDocument` in `doc` variable and currently edited `NotesDocument` are not the same.

Comment: this looks very strange. OnChange(?) event in LotusScript processes documents in a view. You mean when StartDate field change you want to do something with all documents having the same "old" StartDate (so "specialdate" in your code is the old value of current document StartDate?

Comment: I think you need to show us the actual code, not some "similar" code. Something is obviously missing. I agree with Normunds that looping through all docs in an OnChange event seems very strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a global variable like "StartDateOld" in form's `(Global)` / `(Declarations)`.

Assign the value of field "StartDate" to this variable in `PostOpen` event.

You can use the old value in variable "StartDateOld" in `OnChange` event then.

Don't forget to set the changed value to "StartDateOld" at the end of `OnChange` event's code.

This works for a document in edit mode. I don't really understand what you want to achieve with your code running through the view though...

Comment: Thanks Knut. Following those steps I am able to get the behavior that I want.